# Prove that a sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ defined by $a_1=-\frac14$ and $-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_na_{n+1}+4}4$ is convergent and find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I would like to verify my attempt and deduction. The task is as follows:

> Prove that a sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ defined by $a_1=-\frac14$ and $$-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_na_{n+1}+4}4$$ is convergent and find its limit.

This is what I have so far:

$$-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_na_{n+1}+4}4\iff a_{n+1}(a_n+4)+4=0\tag 1$$

I computed a few terms:

$a_2(a_1+4)=-4\implies a_2=-\frac{16}{15}\\a_3(a_2+4)=-4\implies a_3=-\frac{15}{11}\\a_4(a_3+4)=-4\implies a_4=-\frac{44}{29}$

I assumed $a_n<0\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N$.

Then, from $(1)$ and $a_{n+1}<0$, it follows

$\begin{aligned}a_{n+1}(a_n+4)&=-4\\\implies a_n+4&>0\\\implies a_n&>-4\end{aligned}$

Then, inductively, if $\,0>a_1>\ldots>a_{m-1}>a_m$ for some $m\in\Bbb N,$ we have $\begin{aligned}a_{m-1}+4&>a_m+4>0\\\implies \frac1{a_{m-1}+4}&<\frac1{a_m+4}\\\implies \color{red}{a_m}=-\frac4{a_{m-1}+4}&>-\frac4{a_m+4}=\color{red}{a_{m+1}}\end{aligned}$

So, the sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ is monotonic and bounded and, therefore, convergent.

Also, we can prove a stronger statement:

$a_n>-2\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N$.

$$\begin{aligned}a_n+4&>-2+4=2>0\\\implies -\frac1{a_n+4}&>-\frac12\\\implies a_{n+1}=-\frac4{a_n+4}&>-\frac42=-2\end{aligned}$$

Plugging the limit into $(1)$, we get
$$L^2+4L+4=(L+2)^2=0\iff L=-2$$

Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=-2$.

Is there any mistake in my assumptions and conclusions and should I do any steps in a different order?

I know I couldn't prove $a_n<0\quad\forall n$ by induction since the function $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{-4\}\to\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ defined by $$f(x)=-\frac4{x+4}$$
isn't monotonic on the whole domain, just on $(-\infty,-4)$ and $(-4,+\infty)$ separately.

Also, when I considered writing $a_n=\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ and then
$$\begin{aligned}a_{n+1}&=\frac{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}\\&=-\frac4{\frac{x_n}{y_n}+4}\\&=\frac{-4y_n}{x_n+4y_n}\end{aligned}$$
and assuming $x_{n+1}=-4y_n$ and $y_{n+1}=x_n+4y_n$, I obtained the homogenous recurrence
$$\begin{aligned}y_{n+1}&=-4y_{n-1}+4y_n\\\iff y_{n+1}-4y_n+4y_{n-1}&=0\end{aligned}$$ with a characteristic polynomial
$$\lambda^2-4\lambda+4=(\lambda-2)^2$$ with a multiple root, so I thought I would overcomplicate.

Thank you very much!

Comment: actually $a_n$ is $> -4 \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and so you don't need to worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-4A_{n+1}=A_n A_{n+1}+4$$

Let $A_n=\frac{B_{n-1}}{B_n}$
$$-4\frac{B_n}{B_{n+1}}=\frac{B_{n-1}}{B_n} \frac{B_n}{B_{n+1}}+4$$
$$\implies 4B_{n+1}+4 B_n+B_{n-1}=0$$
Let $B_n=t^n$, then
$$\implies 4t+4+t^{-1}\implies t=-1/2.$$
Then $B_n=(Pn+Q)(-2)^{-n}$, $$ A_n=-2\frac{P(n-1)+Q}{Pn+Q}=-2\frac{n-1+R}{n+R}$$
$$A_1=-1/4 \implies R=1/7.$$
Finally, we have the solution to $(1)$ as
$$A_n=\frac{12-14n}{7n+1} \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}A_n=-2.$$

Comment: May I ask how you've chosen the substitution $A_n=\frac{B_{n-1}}{B_n}$? Was the strategy to cancel $B_n$ on the RHS or something else?

Comment: I found an approach with a similar substitution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227568/823281).

Comment: @Dolphin This one is very simple. In fact you can solve $T_nT_{n-1}+AT_n+BT_{n-1}+C=0$ taking $T_{n}+A=V_{n}/V_{n-1}$ you will get a linear equation in $V_n,V_{n-1},V_{n-2}$..

Comment: Following your comment, I wrote $T_nT_{n-1}+AT_n+BT_{n-1}+C=0$ as 

$\begin{aligned}\left(\frac{V_n}{V_{n-1}}-A\right)\cdot\frac{V_{n-1}}{V_{n-2}}+B\left(\frac{V_{n-1}}{V_{n-2}}-A\right)+C&=0\\\frac{V_n-AV_{n-1}}{V_{n-2}}+B\frac{V_{n-1}-AV_{n-2}}{V_{n-2}}+C&=0\\V_n-(A-B)V_{n-1}-(AB-C)V_{n-2}&=0\end{aligned}$

and in $A_{n+1}A_n+4A_{n+1}+4,$ we have $A=4, B=0, C=4$ and I got $t^2+4t+4=0$ and I get $t=-2$ instead of $t=-\frac12$.

Comment: @Dolphin carry on till the end get the final answer for $A_n$  will match. dont leave it half way.

Comment: @Dolphin you have made a slight error of sign you would get $t^2-4t+4=0 \implies t=2$..Now you proceed to get $T_n$, you will get what I got.Cheers

Comment: thank you very much for your time and patience! Cheers!

Comment: @Dolphin T\You are welcome.